# Raspberry Pi 2b won't produce HDMI output, both LED's on

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot-issues

I have a Rasberry Pi 2b running raspian. It was previously working, however whenever I try to turn it on both LEDs come on prmenantly but nothing is outputted on HDMI.

My TV does change from saying that nothing is connected to their is no signal, if that's of any use.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a different SD card? Maybe something was overwritten. Did you try a different Pi with the same card and the same monitor?

Comment: `It was previously working` - what changed?

Comment: @JaromandaX "what changed?" - one never steps in the same river twice they say.